# Blurred values gets display when i selected the grid values from grid

Tags: css, vue.js

First image link is my requirement.Some fields i should not show up in the grid. So i have blurred the fields by using CSS
 [image]
Second image link is the issue. The blurred fields gets display when i choose CTRL + A or by selecting the value from mouse.
[image]

Please help!!!

Comment: Are you only obfuscating these values only with client side code? Because if you are, that is one problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `user-select: none` on those `td` elements to prevent them from being selected.

Note that [`user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) requires `-webkit` and `-moz` prefixes.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    items: [{
      col1: "123",
      col2: "456"
    },{
      col1: "789",
      col2: "012"
    }]
  }
});
```

```css
.no-select {
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
}

.blur {
  filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>Col2 (with no-select)</th>
        <th>Col2 (without no-select)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>{{ item.col1 }}</td>
        <td class="no-select blur">{{ item.col2 }}</td>
        <td class=" blur">{{ item.col2 }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```